# Understanding projective ambiguity

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry, projective-space

From H&Z Multiple View Geometry

> This ambiguity arises because it is possible to apply a projective
> transformation (rep- resented by a 4x4 matrix $H$) to each point $X_i$,
> and on the right of each camera matrix $P_j$ , without changing the
> projected image points, thus
>
> $P_jX_i = (P_jH^{−1})(HX_i)$. (1.1)
>
> There is no
> compelling reason to choose one set of points and camera matrices over
> the other. The choice of $H$ is essentially arbitrary, and we say that
> the reconstruction has a projective ambiguity, or is a *projective
> reconstruction*. However, the good news is that this is the worst that
> can happen. It is possible to reconstruct a set of points from two
> views, up to an unavoidable projective ambiguity. Well, to be able to
> say this, we need to make a few qualifications; there must be suffi-
> ciently many points, at least seven, and they must not lie in one of
> various well-defined *critical configurations*.

I'm confused about what exactly is a "projective ambiguity" and what 1.1 is trying to say.

I understand that

$P_jX_i = (P_jH^{−1})(HX_i) = P_j(H^{-1}H)X_i = P_jIX_i=P_jX_i$

However, what about this is ambiguous and why do we care that $P_iX_i = P_jIX_i$ ? More importantly, where's the loss of information? I wish I could ask more pointed questions but I think the purpose of this passage has flew over my head.

Answer (score 4):

Your input data is $P_jX_i$: the images of the original points $X_i$ under the projections $P_j$. You'd like to reconstruct $X_i$ (and perhaps $P_j$ as well). But for any projective transformation $H$, there exists a set of points $HX_i$ which, when projected with projections $P_jH^{-1}$, leads to the same projected points. Which means that the projected points do not contain enough information to tell you which matrix $H$ (including the case of $H=I$, i.e. the case where you use no $H$ at all) corresponds to the *real* original situation. The reconstruction is only determined up to this one projective transformation of the world coordinates, thus it is ambiguous.

*(Note that I haven't read the book, so I might be completely misunderstanding the context here, although I doubt it.)*

Comment: Thank you. However, I’m still confused on what practical effect this ambiguity has. For example, will the true orientation of an object be unknown, etc. ?

Comment: @Carpetfizz: Can you come up with a orientation-reversing transformation $H$? Yes, of course. So orientation is unknown, as is scale, parallelism, angles and quite a large number of other concepts. You have $15$ real degrees of freedom in a generic projective 3d transformation. $4\times4=16$ for the entries of the matrix, but minus one as multiples of the matrix describe the same operation. So you will require this much additional information to uniquely reconstruct the scene. E.g. if you know the “up” direction, that's 2 real degrees of freedom. If you have a reference length, that's one.